# How can I use a slider to return the number of times a loop is to be performed?

Tags: for-loop, slider, jsxgraph

This smidgen of code (assuming a board has been defined of appropriate size), gives the idea of what I'm trying:

```js
 var s = board.create('slider',[[1,-1],[5,-1],[0,0,10]],{name:'s',snapWidth:1});
 for (let i = 0; i <= s.Value(); i++) {
    var p = board.create('point',[()=>{return i-5;},()=>{return Math.pow(i-5,2)/5;}]);
    }
```

The loop works fine if I replace `s.Value()` with a number; say 10.  But I want the number of points to be plotted to be defined by the slider value.

I've also tried replacing `s.Value()` with `function(){return s.Value();}` but that doesn't work either.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working nearly correct, but does not do what you intend:
The line

```js
var s = board.create('slider',[[1,-1],[5,-1],[0,0,10]], {name:'s',snapWidth:1});
```

creates a slider and initializes it with the value 0 (the second value in the last array). Then, in the subsequent `for`-loop the slider value is used:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= s.Value(); i++) {
  var p = board.create('point',[()=>{return i-5;},()=>{return Math.pow(i-5,2)/5;}]);
}
```

The loop effectly reads `for (let i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {}`. Actually, one point should have been created, but a small numerical error probably prohibits even this.

But anyhow, this is not what you want to do, since the loop is executed only once, namely at initialization time. So far, the code does not react to dragging the slider by the user, i.e. has no event listener registered.

My suggestion would be to create at initalization time all points in a loop, hide them (`visible:false`) and store them in an array. Then, we add an event listener which reacts to dragging of the slider. In that event listener method, we set all points with index `<= s.Value()` visible and the others invisible.
The code looks like this:

```js
var points = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  points.push(
    board.create('point',[
      ()=>{return i-5;},()=>{return Math.pow(i-5,2)/5;}
    ], {
      visible:false, 
      label: { visible: false }
    })
  );
}

s.on('drag', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (i <= s.Value()) {
      points[i].setAttribute({visible:true});
    } else {
      points[i].setAttribute({visible:false});
    }
  }
});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/67d9brcm/2/.

Comment: Thank you very much.  From your answer, it seems that this might not be a "natural" thing to do in JSXGraph - maybe there's a better way to enter a number such as I need?  In fact for my purposes I do need an array of points, which I can create and use.  I simply want the number of points - that is, the length of the array - to be controlled by the user.  Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: The main thing you need is an event listener method, i.e. a function which is executed whenever the user decides to change the slider value. In this event listener you can access the new slider value and adapt the array accordingly.